# Web3.py 'topics'

Tags: web3.py

I have question regarding **topic:**.
I'd want to query and filter for specific transaction below.

````
Transaction Recept Event Logs

Topics
-1st log-
0 - 0xe1fffcc4923d04b559f4d29a8bfc6cda04eb5b0d3c460751c2402c5c5cc9109c
1 - 0x0000000000000000000000007a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d 
-2nd log-
0 - 0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef
1 - 0x0000000000000000000000007a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d
2 - 0x000000000000000000000000cffdded873554f362ac02f8fb1f02e5ada10516f
-3rd log-
0 - 0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef
1 - 0x000000000000000000000000cffdded873554f362ac02f8fb1f02e5ada10516f
2 - 0x000000000000000000000000e83d30715569fa0ef6744e96c7103cc410b82e09
-4th log-
0 - 0x1c411e9a96e071241c2f21f7726b17ae89e3cab4c78be50e062b03a9fffbbad1 ```
````

My code
Problem: When I add **2nd log 0** on 3rd **topics:**, it gets me empty.

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
from hexbytes import HexBytes
w3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider('my addresss....'))
event_signature_hash = Web3.keccak(text="eventName(uint32)").hex()
event_filter = w3.eth.filter({
    "fromBlock":"latest",
    'topics':['0xe1fffcc4923d04b559f4d29a8bfc6cda04eb5b0d3c460751c2402c5c5cc9109c', '0x0000000000000000000000007a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d']
})
```

For transaction above I was able filter only 1st log only. And When I tried to add 2nd logs on **topics** it returns empty...  Is there any way to filter whole log using **topics**?

How I did to get *2nd log 2* and **3rd log 2**

```
    'topics': [
[
    '0xe1fffcc4923d04b559f4d29a8bfc6cda04eb5b0d3c460751c2402c5c5cc9109c',
    '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef',
    '0x1c411e9a96e071241c2f21f7726b17ae89e3cab4c78be50e062b03a9fffbbad1'
    ],
[
    '0x0000000000000000000000007a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d',
    '0x000000000000000000000000539562e68e37041729d5a8084b4ce982b0398afd'
],
[
    '0x000000000000000000000000cffdded873554f362ac02f8fb1f02e5ada10516f',
    '0x000000000000000000000000e83d30715569fa0ef6744e96c7103cc410b82e09'
]
```

Comment: Please post **in plain text** (no links or images) what type of data your are trying to filter.

Comment: @goodvibration thanks for reply... I will edit post 1 sec

Comment: Please refrain from updating your question according to the given answers. If you have another question, then please post it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the official documentation](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html#event-log-filters):

> Given a transaction log with topics [A, B], the following topic filters will yield a match:
>
> - [] “anything”
> - [A] “A in first position (and anything after)”
> - [None, B] “anything in first position AND B in second position (and anything after)”
> - [A, B] “A in first position AND B in second position (and anything after)”
> - [[A, B], [A, B]] “(A OR B) in first position AND (A OR B) in second position (and anything after)”

So in order to retrieve the 1st log and the 2nd log, you need to use:

```
'topics': [
    [
        '0xe1fffcc4923d04b559f4d29a8bfc6cda04eb5b0d3c460751c2402c5c5cc9109c',
        '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef'
    ],
    [
        '0x0000000000000000000000007a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d'
    ]
]
```

Comment: You are legend. I think I might figure out how to do it ! thank you :D

Comment: if u wouldn't mind could u show me how to do
 2nn log - 2  as well? I added another  array after 2nd nested but seems to be not working...