# Web3.py defining only last topic (is there 'and anything before' option?)

Tags: web3.py, topics

I was checking this post:
[Web3.py 'topics'](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/90526/web3-py-topics)

and this documentation:
https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html#event-log-filters

I see here, that I have various methods for defining the first topics and then those that come after are not relevant. Is there a "reverse" option, to define the last topics and those before can be anything?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation you link if you know the last topic is the third then you can include `None` in first two entries

```
[None, None, B]
```

Comment: That is true, but with your expression, we have fixed two "None" entries. I am wondering if it is possible to define only the last topic while the number of topics before it is unknown.

Comment: @Penko_Mlakar Sorry, but I haven't found a way to filter by the "last" topic.